# Can hive process table on different hdfs cluster?

Tags: hive

Can one hive instance store different tables across hdfs clusters. and then do hive ql on these tables?

My use case is that I have one hive table on one hdfs cluster. I want to do some process on it with hive ql and have the output been written to another hdfs cluster. I wish to achieve this directly only by hive, not need to run through some dump / copy / import process. So Is that possible? I don't really think it is possible, however, I notice a design page on :

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27837073

in it , it said that :

"Note that, even today, different partitions/tables can span multiple dfs's, and hive does not enforce any restrictions. Those dfs's can be in different data centers also"

except this, I failed to google anything related.

anyone have any ideas on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this. you can go with mirroring (use tools like Apache Falcon). In this case you have data stored in both the clusters. If you want to query across clusters having a different table without mirroring then use tools like Apache Drill which can join data from different datasources. it currently supports hive,mongo,json, kudu etc